# Search suggestion box with jQuery and AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
var searchUser = function(searchQuery){
    var request = $.ajax({
        url:"search.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { search:searchQuery},
        success: function(reply){
            $("#search-box").css("display", "block");
            $("#search-box").html(reply);
        }
    });
}
```

I know this is a terrible way of doing it, right? How else would I best go about outputting the search result to my `#search-box`? Right now, I send an AJAX request to my search.php file which returns all the HTML of the search. Surely this wouldn't be good from a performance perspective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You should ensure your spacing is consistent.
- Since you're using a function *expression* rather than a *declaration*, you should terminate the line with a semicolon.
- You aren't making any use of the `request` variable, so why even declare it?
- You aren't taking advantage of method chaining. This is causing you to construct two jQuery objects for `#search-box` when you only need one.
- You're right in that this is not the best way to handle it; consider returning JSON or XML.
- You have a `success` callback but not an `error` callback. In this particular case I don't imagine it would be too bad (your search box will just remain hidden, presumably), but you may want to add one anyway.

Here's how I think your code could look.

```
var searchUser = function(searchQuery) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "search.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { search: searchQuery },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            var resultList = response.reduce(function(accumulator, value) {
                return accumulator + "<li>" + value + "</li>";
            }, "<ul>");
/* alternative for older browsers:
            var resultList = "<ul>";
            $.each(response, function(index, element) {
                resultList += "<li>" + element + "</li>";
            });
*/
            resultList += "</ul>";
            $("#search-box").html(resultList).show();
        },
        error: function() {
            $("#search-box").html("An error occurred. Search suggestions could not be loaded.");
        }
    });
};
```

`search.php` would then have to do something like:

```php
$results = array("suggest", "suggestion", "suggested", "suggesting");
die(json_encode($results));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for my insight. I have done everything (bar the JSON but which Il do later) you said and its now looking a lot better.